# How to effect constraints on monogodb fields

Tags: python, performance, mongodb, constraints

I was wanting to implement some constraints on the datatypes of the document fields but am not interested in any of the other features of ODMs (I suspect I will just use `pymongo`). Does there exists a light weight package that I can use to add constraints to my collection fields?

Or is this just typically done in python before the input is inserted into the database? e.g., something like:

```
def varchar_20(input):
    return re.match(r'^\w+$', input) > 0 and len(input) <= 20
```

Also, would this constraint checking within `python` be likely to cause significant performance issues for a medium-high volume write application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't have a way to validate constraints on the server. This is work that would be done on a client. Depending on the pig roaming language, some drivers offer a way to check some basic constraints, although they're often quite simple things, like length of a string.

Many object layers offer a way to do custom validation and this is where you'd insert your custom logic. PyMongo does not, but there are a number of additional frameworks that can use PyMongo and add validations: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.4.1/tools.html

As to scalability, it's really hard to say without a lot more specifics.

Comment: These are the ODM/ORM-like frameworks that I had come across and wasn't really interested in other than their schema-enforcing abilities. I guess I could just limit my usage of one of them to its validation abilities. I hadn't seen Ming before perhaps that is the answer.

Comment: Sounds like you need part of the support, or you'll need to write your own. I can't say which is the right one for you, but many don't add much perf hit if you keep things simple.